# Flipping Image Python

Tags: python, image, jython, image-rotation, jes

I am trying to flip an image horizontally.

From this:

[image: Original Pic]

To This:

[image: Flipped Pic]

But I keep getting it mirrored half way.

Like This:

[image: Result I get]

I am trying to reverse the x-axis index and I don't understand why it is being divided.

```
def flip(picture):
    height = getHeight(picture)
    width = getWidth(picture)
    newPicture = makeEmptyPicture(width, height)
    x2 = width-1
    for x in range(0, width):
        y2 = 0
        for y in range(0, height):
            pxl = getPixel(picture, x, y)
            newPxl = getPixel(picture, x2, y2)
            color = getColor(pxl)
            setColor(newPxl, color)
            y2 = y2+1
        x2 = x2-1
    return picture
```

The rest of my code:

```
def d():    
    f = pickAFile()
    picture = makePicture(f)        
    newPicture = copy(picture)        
    writePictureTo(newPicture, r"D:\FOLDER\newPic4.jpg")
    explore(newPicture)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `flip()` function (like in any function), as mentioned by the other answers, you return `picture` which is the image passed as a parameter of the function but is defined in d()...

It is a matter of `scope` of the variables, so I invite you to have a look again at the discussion we had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17256599/1715716).

Here, you had two choices (you made a melting between the two):

- Modifying directly the `picture` given as parameter
- Creating a `newPicture`, modifying it, and finally returning it

**Details about the 2d option :**

The important thing here is that the `picture` variable belongs to the `d()` function (d() is the scope of it). In the mean time the `newPicture` variable belongs to the `flip()` function (flip() is its scope). So the life time of the newPicture is flip() (i.e. it is destroyed as soon as you terminate the execution of the flip() function, while returning). And d() doesn't know anything about this newPicture, unless you return it to d().

So, in short (assuming we are talking about the second option):

**1)** Create a function that takes a `picture` as parameter (flip())

**2)** Inside flip(), create a local variable `newPicture` and modify that one only, such that the original `picture` remains unchanged

**3)** Return the newly updated `newPicture` to the parent `scope`. Here d() is calling flip(), so it is the parent scope. We have to create a 3d variable (which belongs to d() scope), to keep a hand on what was returned by flip():

```
def flip(picture)
    # Create newPicture
    # Modify newPicture (using the information from the "picture" parameter)
    setColor(newPicture, ...)
    ...
    return newPicture

def d():
    file = PickAFile()
    original_pic = makePicture(file) 
    finalNewPicture = flip(original_pic)     # {1}
    show(finalNewPicture)
```

{1}: Here we assign the value returned by flip (i.e. `newPicture`) to the variable of higher scope `finalNewPicture` (handler)...

I hope it helps you to understand the logic behind this. It is like ***Russian dolls***: newPicture is used inside flip(), which is used inside d(), ...

---

**EDIT :**

I also want to give an explanation about the 1st option...

**1)** Create a function that takes a `picture` as parameter (flip())

**2)** Inside flip(), modify directly the higher scoped `picture` variable

**3)** Do not return anything from flip()

This would result in this :

```
def flip(picture)
    # Simply modify the variable "picture", given as a parameter
    setColor(picture, ...)
    ...
    # Do not return anything

def d():
    file = PickAFile()
    original_pic = makePicture(file) 
    flip(original_pic)                     # {1}
    show(original_pic)
```

{1}: Here flip() made the changes directly on the input picture, so we can display the original modified picture directly (`original_pic`). No need for an intermediate handler variable.

---

***Code for option 1 :*** (as you already have it working for option 2)

```
def flip(picture):
  height = getHeight(picture)
  width = getWidth(picture)

  x2=width-1
  for x in range(0, width/2):   # Only process the half way
    y2=0
    for y in range(0, height):
      # swap pix and pix2
      pxl = getPixel(picture, x, y)
      pxl2 = getPixel(picture, x2, y2)
      color = getColor(pxl)
      color2 = getColor(pxl2)
      setColor(pxl2, color)
      setColor(pxl, color2)
      y2=y2+1
    x2=x2-1  

def d():    
  f = pickAFile()
  original_picture = makePicture(f)        
  flip2(original_picture)        
  show(original_picture)

d()
```

***Note :*** flip could have been widely simplified as follows :

```
def flip2(picture):
  height = getHeight(picture)
  width = getWidth(picture)

  for x in range(0, width/2):   # Only process the half way
    for y in range(0, height):
      # swap pix and pix2
      pxl = getPixel(picture, x, y)
      pxl2 = getPixel(picture, width-1-x, y)
      color = getColor(pxl)
      color2 = getColor(pxl2)
      setColor(pxl2, color)
      setColor(pxl, color2)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def flip(picture):
  height = getHeight(picture)
  width = getWidth(picture)
  newPicture = makeEmptyPicture(width, height)
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      color = getColor(getPixel(picture, x, y))
      setColor(getPixel(newPicture, width-1-x, y), color)
  return newPicture
```

How about this?  I just removed the `x2`/`y2` stuff which didn't seem necessary to me.  Otherwise it should work this way.  I found no true bug in your code, just the returning of the `picture` instead of `newPicture` at the end.  But that should not have lead to a mirroring either.

Answer (score 6):

You are changing the pixels in the original picture instead of the newly created newPicture. Also, you are returning the original (now modified) picture.

You should have

```
newPxl = getPixel(newPicture, x2,y2)
```

and you should end with

```
return newPicture
```

Also, I think your code flips the image around the horizontal axis, not the vertical as your images show.

Answer (score 3):

> OpenCV provides a function to flip an  image.

```
void flip(array src, array dst, int flipCode)
```

Flips a 2D array around vertical, horizontal or both axes.

Parameters:

- `src` – The source Array
- `dst` – The destination array; will have the same size and same type as src
- `flipCode` – Specifies how to flip the array: 0 means flipping around the x-axis, positive (e.g., 1) means flipping around y-axis, and negative (e.g., -1) means flipping around both axes.The function flip flips the array in one of three different ways (row and column indices are 0-based).

Example code:

```
cv.flip(original_image,flipped_image,1);
```

Edit: You can also assign the flipped image:

```
flipped_image = cv2.flip(src=original_image, flipCode=1)
```